# How to Map ImageMagick commands to .net code using Magick.net

Tags: .net, imagemagick, magick.net

Let's say I want to transform the transparent background of an image into white (flatten a png):
A simple google search points me to:
`convert -flatten image.png noTransparency.png`.
This works fine if I invoke imageMagick from the command line. 
But let's say I want to use the .NET wrapper **magick.net** to do the same thing.
Neither Google nor magick.net's documentation is very helpful for this case.

Same thing happens with 
`convert original.png +transparent "#E6B15A" singleColor.png`
(A way to create a new image containing only a specific color from the original)
I can't find ANY way to do this using the magick.NET wrapper

Why is so hard to map imageMagick commands into **.net** code using magick.net??

Is there any way I could use magick.net to execute imageMagick scripts instead?
I could easily create a **cmd** Process from .net and call imageMagick commands from there, but if there is a wrapper it must be for some reason...
Is there any good and extensive magick.net documentation that I'm missing?

Answer (score 9):

I am sorry but there is no extensive version of the documentation available at this moment. I have only created a couple of examples and documented them on the website. I don't have the time/team to create more and better documentation. But I can help you with the answer to both questions.

`convert -flatten image.png noTransparency.png`

This should actually be written like this:

`convert image.png -flatten noTransparency.png`

First `image.png` is read and then it is flattened and written to `noTransparency.png`. But in ImageMagick it 'secretly' adds another image that has the same size as `image.png` and uses that to flatten `image.png`. You can write it like this in Magick.NET:

```
using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
{
  MagickImage imagePng = new MagickImage("image.png");

  // 'add background'
  MagickImage background = new MagickImage(imagePng.BackgroundColor, imagePng.Width, imagePng.Height);
  images.Add(background);

  // image.png
  images.Add(imagePng);

  // +flatten
  using (MagickImage result = images.Flatten())
  {
    // noTransparency.png
    result.Write("noTransparency.png");
  }
}
```

But you can also write it like this:

```
using (MagickImage imagePng = new MagickImage("image.png"))
{
  imagePng.ColorAlpha(imagePngg.BackgroundColor);
  result.Write("noTransparency.png");
}
```

And your other example cannot be translated with the current release (7.0.0.0016) because +transparent is not yet supported.

`convert original.png +transparent "#E6B15A" singleColor.png1`

In the next version you will be able to do this:

```
using (MagickImage original = new MagickImage("original.png"))
{
  original.InverseTransparent(new MagickColor("#E6B15A"));
  original.Write("singleColor.png");
}
```

But you could do it like this for now:

```
using (MagickImage original = new MagickImage("original.png"))
{
  original.InverseOpaque(new MagickColor("#E6B15A"), MagickColor.Transparent);
  original.Write("singleColor.png");
}
```

And you can always ask for more help here: https://magick.codeplex.com/discussions.

Comment: For me, the `MagickImageCollection`+`Flatten` example works great. The `InverseTransparent` example is not yet available, and the `InverseOpaque` example produces a completely white image.

Comment: It seems I completely forgot to add the InverseTransparent method. I created an issue for this: https://magick.codeplex.com/workitem/1365. You can ask for help about InverseOpaque here: https://magick.codeplex.com/discussions

Comment: Just to clarify, the example that creates a canvas and flattens the images does exactly what I want, and I'm not the OP. :) @dlemstra

Comment: Is there a Wiki somewhere where we can crowd-source these kinds of how-tos for Magick.Net?

Comment: At this moment there is no such wiki but maybe we could do that on github? https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET